# Minimize currently focused window keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, window, focus, minimize

I'm trying to find a keyboard shortcut in 17.10 to minimize the currently focused window.

There doesn't seem to be one in Keyboard settings.

Tried adding a new shortcut, but not sure what the command is to minimize.

Any ideas?

Comment: Minimize only one window or all windows? For all windows you can use Ctrl+Alt+D. Not sure if there is one for a single window but you can click close them from the doc if you use dash-to-dock.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to minimise the focussed window.